# Cannot send index in the second $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

Here I have a simple $http request where I get several quizzes. Then I need to add in each quiz results. But i = obtained values instead of index

```
$http.get(url).success(function(response) {
                $scope.quizes = response.quizes;
                for(var i=0; i<$scope.quizes.length; i++){
                    $http.get('url?filter=quizId,eq,' + $scope.quizes[i].id +'&transform=1').success(function(i, response){
                         return  function (result){
                            $scope.quizes[i].results = response; 
                         }
                    }(i,  response));
                }
            });
```

How to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
angular.forEach($scope.quizes, function(quiz, $index){
  $http.get('url' + quiz.id +'&transform=1').then(function(result){
                    $scope.quizes[$index].results = result.data.results; 
                });
            });
```

Comment: I recommend using angular.forEach instead of using the standard javascript for. It's syntax would be 
angular.forEach($scope.quizes, function(quiz, $index){});